# An explanation of memory usage on Windows server 2003

Tags: windows, memory, service

We've been working on a bit of puzzle at work. We have an application service installed on two machines, both running Windows server 2003. These services do exactly the same thing.

However once loaded, one of the services uses 200mb less than the other service.

We're at a bit of a loss to what might be causing this discrepancy.

I was wondering if there was some kind of server setting that would cause an application to use more memory (heap block size) or anything to explain this.

If anyone has any ideas on what may be causing this, or how to find out what is causing this I'd be very grateful.

Comment: belongs on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run [VMMap from sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533) and analyze each server instance. This will help you track down what type of memory allocations are different.

Comment: We have exact the same problem could you point out what the reason was in your case?